# Is "thank's" an alternative correct spelling?

Tags: american-english, orthography, apostrophe, politeness, greengrocers-apostrophe

My colleague who is American spells "thank's" (with an apostrophe) and when I ask him why he said because it's "more formal" and "he uses American English".

Is this true? Can you really spell "thank's" in American English and is it really considered more formal?

EDIT: Well, I *do* know it's not true. I just wanted to have someone *native* explain it so it is more persuasive. And I have seen this incorrect spelling so many time that judging *just by usage* - it is correct :) Just Google search gives about 2,500,000 occurrences... You may even be easily mislead by a [dictionary title](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thank's) and it doesn't say it's wrong!

Comment: Your colleague may be American, but he is not fully on top of his language.

Comment: Your colleague will not be able to come up with a single dictionary that has an entry for *thank's*, or a single book that uses it anywhere. He only just invented that reasoning fresh on the spot, possibly to cover up his egregious error, or just to mess with you.

Comment: Again, why -2 points? Evidently the question is not so trivial if a native speaker stated this. And it's difficult to find resources on internet on the *incorrect* spelling of a word. It's a pity that we don't have a *rule* that whoever votes down a question must state why they think the question is bad.

Comment: The competent answer below will give me the needed support in talking to him. He would not believed me if I just said him the same as he is "native" and I am "non-native". It's relatively easy to find on internet how something *is* spelled but it's usually impossible to find that something is *not* spelled a certain way.

Comment: Nobody here is declining the fact that there are over 2,500,000 people in the world with horrible understanding of the language/spelling. A big number of results in Google isn't a proof of correctness. Could you run a script to get the occurrences of that word in actual printed books (or even PDFs)?
**Also**, *please* read an article carefully before sharing it! That link's just another keyword search trick to get more visitors. Do you find a single entry to **thank's** in there? Nope! It just redirects you to the article **thank** & misleads you so to get more visitors & more ad money.

Comment: @Neeku: I didn't use the 2.5 mil. google hits as an argument for correctness of the spelling, but as an argument for the legitimacy of the question! I have received two downvotes for the question without explanation of why somebody considers the question as "not showing research effort; unclear or not useful". It looks just like another example of arrogant reaction from native speakers who feel offended by questions they consider as two trivial. I was trying to prove that the question is not two trivial, if so many people (and even many native) repeat the same error.

Comment: In my experience it is very common for immigrants/foreigners to have a better grasp of English than Americans, because they learned it formally whereas we grew up speaking it and didn't pay attention in school.

Comment: This edit looks better @HonzaZidek. I have to say the previous one did deserve a down-vote (not the original one, IMHO), however I haven't down-voted for this question, because it's a decent one, AND the more exposure to these sinful errors, the better! People should stop making terrible mistakes like this.

Comment: The incorrect usage of the apostrophe i.e. [The grocer's apostrophe](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Greengrocer-S-Apostrophe.htm), is rife among English native speakers. It doesn't matter at all in speech, but people are so used to seeing apostrophes written everywhere and many will not have actually learnt/studied their use (for whatever reason) and hence these spelling mistakes occur. Think of *Thank's* as yet another example of (poor) spelling similar to **loose** instead of *lose* and **it's** when the possessive form should be written *its*.

Comment: Some American's have problem's with apostrophe's ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`'s` shows either possession, or when the following word i.g. *is*/*us*/... is abbreviated. Therefore, in this case, `'s` can only be used if you're talking about something that belongs to "*thank*", which makes no sense at all; nor if you're saying "*thank is*" which does not make sense, either.

The `s` at the end of the word "*thanks*" is just a plural `s` and adding any apostrophe before that is just an error. Native speakers in each language may happen to make mistakes.

> Word origin:
>
> Date: 1300-1400 Origin: Plural of *thank* 'gratefulness' (11-17
>   centuries), from Old English *thanc* 'thought, gratefulness'

Says the subscription-only LDOCE.

To make your appreciation/gratefulness in a more formal way, you could say:

> *Thank you so much for your assistance*.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment, if "*thank*" is being used as a verb, `s` would be added to make it third person singular:

> *She always thanks her mother for the meals she cooks*.

However, there's another note that can be a common mistake among learners or non-native speakers who happen to use the verb form with that third person singular `s` for all persons; so instead of saying

"**Thank God**" or "**Thank heavens**" or "**Thank goodness**",

they'd say:

"<del>Thanks God</del>", etc.

Here, the full sentence would be: "*I thank God for ...*", and obviously, "I" is first person, rather than the third.

Comment: If one considers the verb "to thank", the s could also be a third-person s.

Comment: Right @painfulenglish. I'll edit and add this to my answer.

Comment: It's also an error in British English, but quite a common one (in Greengrocer's English). I think it's worth saying that generally, if you want to sound more "formal", you should use "thank you" rather than "thanks".

Comment: An apostrophe can donate one or more missing letters at any point in a word, and certainly not only in is/us. Thin of the common poetic "e'er" for "ever".